# .NET Async on the Web - Whats the point if i can just spin new cloud instances?

Tags: .net, architecture, asynchronous, cloud

If the point of async is to enable more requests on a single box, does the cloud's offering of  as many instances as i want negate the need for tons of requests on a single box, therefore negating my need of async?

I'm not trying to make an argument for performance-free or sloppy coding, i would just like to know if there are other technical issues that become problems perhaps by adding more boxes to avoid async-- too many connections to the db?

Answer (score 3):

> If the point of async is to enable more requests on a single box, does the cloud's offering of as many instances as i want negate the need for tons of requests on a single box, therefore negating my need of async?

No, it doesn't negate the need.  Allowing more requests on a single box reduces the total number of cloud instances you'd need, which in turn reduces costs significantly.  Since you pay per instance (ie: for compute time), getting more work out of each instance directly impacts your overall cost.

Comment: +1, but from a purely technical standpoint, the only technical point I can think of is the licensing of the SQL product (if applicable).

Comment: completely true, if the license limits connections that is the minority but still technical in nature :)